# Can we partition a CSV file while reading it from HDFS?

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I am trying to read a huge csv file into spark and load it into a snowflake table.
To read a csv file, we have the following syntax in pyspark:

```
file_df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').option('inferSchema', 'true').load('/tmp/dirpath/data/')
```

schema of my csv file:

```
schema = StructType([
        StructField("CUSTKEY", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("NAME", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ADDRESS", StringType(), True),
        StructField("NATIONID", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("PHONE", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ACCTBAL", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("COMMENT", StringType(), True),
    ])
```

To read data from an RDBMS table, we have below syntax:

```
yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                       .option("dbtable", s"(${execQuery}) as year2016")
                       .option("user", devUserName)
                       .option("password", devPassword)
                       .option("partitionColumn","epochVals")
                       .option("lowerBound", minEp)
                       .option("upperBound", maxEp)
                       .option("numPartitions",15)
                       .load()
```

To partition the data while reading from a table, we have the option `partitionColumn` where we can specify the partition column (This is an old scenario & my data belongs to a single partition of a hive table) where a column `epochVals` has almost unique values and the parameter `numPartitions` helps to partition the data into exact number of partitions (15 is a random number taken to explain the scenario) So while reading data, spark has 15 partitions to arrange the data into.

Now my csv file is of size 35GB. We can always `repartition` a dataframe as per requirement in the code down the line but is there an option in spark to partition data while reading a csv file ? If I already know the schema of the CSV file and a column `custkey` that contains unique values, can I use the `partitionColumn` and `numpartitions` parameters in the spark.read.format('csv') statement ? If not how can I decide optimum number of partitions to `repartition` the data after loading csv file?
Could anyone let me know if it is possible to do what I asked above ?

Comment: I the file compressed? CSV files can be (they are automatically) split if there is no compression or the compression format is BZip2

Comment: The file is on HDFS already. I see the files have `.deflate` extension. So I think they are compressed. If it is splittable, how can I apply the splitting mechanism ?

Comment: AFAIK `deflate` is similar to `gz` that is not splittable, never tried myself though. If it was splittable, spark will automatically split it based on number of executors

Answer (score 0):

Answering the title of the question: No there is not if using spark.read. You need to `repartition` afterwards the dataframe.